# How to configure IntelliJ to run of any single spec

Tags: intellij-idea, rspec

In IntelliJ (idea-IU-172.3757.52) I can right click a folder containing specs and to do "Run-->All specs in folder", but trying to right click a single spec and running it doesn't even show to option to do "Run".

if in 'Run/Debug Configurations" I will select

```
configuration-->Mode-->Spec script
```

and specify a path to a single test I could run that specific test but no other test.

I know it is possible to configure IntelliJ to run any single spec, but not sure how to configure it.

Run all specs in folder config:

[image]

run a single spec config:

[image]

Project structure modules:

[image]

file example in project tree:

[image]

Comment: What version of IDEA do you use? Would it be possible to attach a screenshot from File | Project Structure | Modules and from the project tree (so that the spec folder can be seen).

Comment: hi Olivia I'm using the latest idea, idea-IU-172.3757.52, and I've added the files.

Comment: Could you please specify what kind of project is that? A Java module with some RSpec tests? Do you have a Gemfile with `rspec` gem in it?